# Why does the compiler complains when `none const copy constructor` is used?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor, move-semantics

As the subject, the code below is right.

```
#include<iostream>

class ABC     
{  public:  
    ABC() 
    {
        std::cout<< "default construction" << std::endl;
    }

    ABC(ABC& a) 
    {
        std::cout << "copy construction" << std::endl;
    } 

};                         

int main()   
{  
   ABC c1 = ABC(); 
}
```

It could not compile successfully:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()': 
<source>:25:13: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'ABC&' to an rvalue of type 'ABC'
   25 |    ABC c1 = ABC();
      |             ^~~~~
<source>:10:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'ABC::ABC(ABC&)'
   10 |     ABC(ABC& a)
      |         ~~~~~^
```

However, it could compile if replace the `ABC(ABC& a)` by `ABC(const ABC&)`.I know it has some relation with the keyword `const`.But i could not figure out why.

You could check it on https://godbolt.org/z/jNL5Bd. I am a novice in C++.I would be grateful to have some help with this question.

Comment: That doesn't happen when using `clang` with modern settings. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @tadman You could check it on https://godbolt.org/z/jNL5Bd. With the opintion "-std=c++11"

Comment: Sure, but I live in 2020 so I use the modern standard. Is there a reason you're stuck with C++11? If so, feel for you.

Comment: @tadman There are many compilers which could not support C++20, especially for embedded system.

Comment: By design, C++ does (before guaranteed elision) not allow a temporary to be passed by non-`const` reference.   In `ABC c1 = ABC()`,  `ABC()` constructs a temporary passes it to a copy constructor.   If that copy constructor accepts a `const` reference, all is okay. If it accepts a non-`const` reference, then the temporary cannot be passed. The philosophy behind the restriction is that an object passed by non-`const` reference can be changed and there is no value in doing that to an object which will immediately cease to exist.  In practice, such things often indicate a design error.

Comment: @Thomas Sablik  Yea, but i still wanna to know why the complier complains(i have to know indeed.).

Comment: The code you have here is not the same as the code you give on compiler explorer. The code here does not give that error. The difference is specifying `const` for the copy constructor parameter.

Comment: @Daniel H I know it has some relation with keyword `const`.But i could figure out why it has such influence.

Comment: A proper copy constructor is either `T(const T&)` or `T(T&&)`, your is neither. Hence, not a copy constructor. Also, you are constructing a temporary in most dialects of the language which cannot be bound to a `T&`.

Comment: Because of the rule (which the compiler is telling you) that you cannot bind a non-const reference to a temporary. Without copy ellision in `ABC c1 = ABC();` ABC() is a temporary and = invokes the copy cosntructor

Answer (score 1):

As the error message said, the temporary `ABC()` can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const, the copy constructor taking `ABC&` can't be used for initialization. (Temporaries could be bound to lvalue-reference to const or rvalue-reference.)

---

PS: Since C++17 the code would compile (which doesn't mean the copy constructor taking lvalue-reference to non-const is a good manner), because [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is guaranteed, the copy construction would be elided completely.

(emphasis mine)

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, **even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects**. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. **The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible**:

Comment: But there's still no justifcation for having a copy constructor with a non-const reference parameter.

Comment: In C++17,  the sequence `const ABC a;  ABC b = a;`  will trigger a diagnostic if the copy constructor of `ABC` accepts a non-`const` reference.    The fact that C++17 guaranteed elision eliminates some cases, does not mean that a copy constructor accepting a non-`const` reference is always appropriate.

Comment: @john I wouldn't even call it a copy constructor, just a weird constructor.

Comment: @ john Why?Could you explain that in detail?

Comment: The why is a different question. It's arguable whether it's a good rule, but Peter gave the philosophy behind the rule in a comment above. In C++ you should always indicate whether a reference, pointer or method is const. It never hurts and sometimes makes the difference between compiling and non-compiling code.

Comment: @john If I understand you correctly, you mean `ABC(const ABC& a)` is a copy constructor while `ABC(ABC& a)` is not.Am i right?

Comment: @sunshilong369 I wouldn't say that (it was Tanveer who said that). `ABC(ABC& a)` is a copy constructor, just a difficient one. If you write `ABC a; ABC b(a);` then your difficient copy constructor does get called and does the right thing.

Comment: Since there seems to be some confusion about what constitutes a "copy constructor", the C++ standard says that all four of these are copy constructors: `ABC(ABC&)`, `ABC(const ABC&)`, `ABC(volatile ABC&)`, and `ABC(const volatile ABC&)`.